# Duplicate email finder for Outlook 2010 with Exchange service

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outlook 2007 reinstall & import from backup, now I have duplicates of everything](https://superuser.com/questions/20725/outlook-2007-reinstall-import-from-backup-now-i-have-duplicates-of-everything)

I'm looking for a tool that can delete all duplicate emails in Outlook 2010.

Any recommendations for free software that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying this here:
http://www.vaita.com/ODIR.asp

It seems to do what i wanted (remove exactly duplicate email-items).
But it takes quite a long time, i have quite a few emails tho, so i will give it some more time.

Comment: well, it finished over night and found all duplicates  :)